# What am I doing wrong with this Java JPanel/JFrame/JButton?

Tags: java, swing

What am I doing wrong with this Java JPanel/JFrame/JButton? This is my program and right now I've been trying to be able to repaint it, but it won't work. Please help! I am a beginner with `JPanel` and `JFrame`. I'm only adding this sentence to allow it to post.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Clicks implements MouseListener
{
    private static int clicks, clickersInt, clickersCost;
    private static JButton clickersB, click;
    private static JLabel clickersL, clicksL;
    private static JPanel panel;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame clicksFrame=new JFrame ("Clicks");
        clicksFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        clicks=0;

        panel=new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        click=new JButton("Click Me!");
        clickersB=new JButton("Cost: 10");
        clickersL=new JLabel("Clickers: "+Integer.toString(clickersInt));
        clicksL=new JLabel("Clicks: "+Integer.toString(clicks));

        click.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                clicks++;
                clicksFrame.remove(panel);
                clicksFrame.add(panel);
                panel.validate();
                panel.repaint();
            }
        });

        clickersB.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                if(clicks>=clickersCost)
                {
                    clickersInt++;
                    clicks-=clickersCost;
                    clickersCost*=2;
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(click);
        panel.add(clicksL);
        panel.add(clickersL);
        panel.add(clickersB);

        clicksFrame.add(panel);
        clicksFrame.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        clicksFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I'm only adding this sentence to allow it to post"* I'm only adding this comment to let you know this phrase made me down vote your question. If you want real help, show some effort into explaining what you're trying to achieve even if you're a beginner. Please consider taking the [tour], going through the [help], reading [ask] and explain clearly where you're stuck and why. What do you expect the `repaint()` method to do with your application when you call it? Why?

Comment: _What am I doing wrong?_ is also too broad. We might guess the goal of the exercise, but you should state what _specific_ result you intended and what actually happened.

Comment: What is the point  of removing and adding the same panel? That is completely unnecessary. Also, when you do dynamically add/remove components then you invoke revalidate() and repaint() on the parent panel, not the component that was added/removed.

Comment: Call `clicksFrame.revalidate()` and `clicksFrame.repaint()` instead of using `panel`, as `clicksFrame` is the container which changed

Comment: Also, simply change the text of `clickersL` and `clicksL`, otherwise nothing will change

Answer (score 0):

So, based on this little snippet...

```
click=new JButton("Click Me!");
clickersB=new JButton("Cost: 10");
clickersL=new JLabel("Clickers: "+Integer.toString(clickersInt));
clicksL=new JLabel("Clicks: "+Integer.toString(clicks));

click.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        clicks++;
        clicksFrame.remove(panel);
        clicksFrame.add(panel);
        panel.validate();
        panel.repaint();
    }
});
```

I would suggest that what you really want to do is...

```
click.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        clicks++;
        clicksL.setText("Clicks: "+Integer.toString(clicks));
    }
});
```

You seem to be of the illusion that changing a variable will some how change another variable which is just a string of characters.  As you've discovered, that's not how this works